# URL Rewriting using web.config file in .net MVC Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-rewriting, web-config

I want to write a rule in web.config so that I can redirect URL.
Only for this keyword in URL(**/resultprocess/**). I want to change domain in URL.

My input URL is : http://A.B.C.D:8082/resultprocess/GetMessage (having any type of input data).

I want output URL : http://M.N.O.P:9092/resultprocess/GetMessage (with same input data).

I have tried follownig rules:

```
 <rewrite>
    <rules>
          <rule name="Rewrite Rule2">
      <match url="/resultprocess(.*)" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{URL}" pattern="/resultprocess(.*)" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://M.N.O.P:9092/{R:0}"/>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
```

But it's not working. Please suggest me, what am I doing wrong?